# Alternating column AND row colors with tabu?

Tags: tables, color, tabu, colortbl

There is a very convenient way to have alternating row colors in `tabu` using `\taburowcolors{ .. }`. But is there a way to do the same thing with columns plus alternating row colors ? What I want basically, is something like:

```
column 1 (blue)... | ....column 2 (blue).......|...........cell 3 (blue).............|    
row 1 (blue)...... | ....row 1 (light blue)... | Tableheader row 1 (lighter blue)... |    
row 2 (blue)...... | ...row 2 (pearl white)... | Tableheader row 2 (light gray)..... |
```

PS: Sorry for the dot-formatting... hope you get the idea. Is this even possible with tabu?

Comment: I don't see how you intend to specify the colours here: I think we need more detail. I'm marking as 'unclear', but flag and I'll reopen.

Answer (score 2):

You can define colors for columns using `\columncolor`. See the example below. For a specific cell, you might use `\cellcolor`. See the `colortbl` docs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{gray}\color{white}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{blue}\color{white}}c}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{bcg}
a & b & c \\
d & \cellcolor{green}{e} & f
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```